# How can i modify jquery datepicker that support Jalali Calander with Dari Months?

Tags: jquery

I searched the net and i didn't find any library that suport jQuery datepicker for Dari
language with jalali converter.

Comment: I think you have to write it your own. As it does not cover each and every language. Also Dari language is usually spoken not mostly written. Do this job and opensource :) best wishes @mehdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I modified the jQuery Datepicker library to support Dari, and Pashto Languages.
here is the library code.

https://gist.github.com/mehdijalal/f883f1129d0163fd7d88

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery Calendars datepicker: http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html

It supports a variety of alternative calendars and is based on the original jQuery Datepicker plugin. The code for all the alternative calendars is included and can be used as the basis for your own extension if needed.

Comment: No this is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

this is http://hasheminezhad.com/datepicker a Jalali datepicker but in Persian, translate it to Dari and enjoy!