# Is there any plugin or customized version of jQuery date picker library that support Dari and Pashto Languages

Tags: jquery, date

How to convert jQuery Datepicker from Georgian to Jalali Date with Dari Months?

Comment: This question can only survive if you do the research yourself, come-up with maybe [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and explain what your tried to make that work and where you didn't succeed. Now it more look like [a request for a recommendation of a library](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I didn't find any solution on the net and than I started customising the jQuery Datepicker Library to convert dates from Georgian calendar to Jalali
calendar with months in Dari languages.

Here is the link to question I had asked before in www.stackoverflow.com

[How can i modify jquery datepicker that support Jalali Calander with Dari Months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784006/how-can-i-modify-jquery-datepicker-that-support-jalali-calander-with-dari-months)

and you can use my customised library which is available here:

https://gist.github.com/mehdijalal/f883f1129d0163fd7d88

Comment: Thanks very much it worked great I appreciate your hard work on customizing it to Dari and Pashto Languages, and converting from Gregorian to Jalali calendar. thanks